# svn branch creation from specific revisions

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Is there any way to make a (svn) branch from specific revisions,
as i want to skip some revisions (in new branch) in my commit history.
For example i have revisions from 1 to 1590 and i want to create a new branch and skip the commits (from revision 1504 to 1574 ) and 
revision#1584, revision#1586, and revision#1587.

Kindly help me i will be thankful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to make a new branch from old revision. One is to set your working copy to old revision (right click > TortoiseSVN > Update to revision), and then make a branch (right click > TortoiseSVN > Branch/tag). After that update to head revision with usual Update command.

Another way is to use repository browser (right click > TortoiseSVN > Repo-browser), choose a revision (click on a button in top-right corner with text HEAD), and then use Ctrl+mouse drag-drop to copy folder (or, as alternative, right click on folder > Copy to).

EDIT: Because you want some later revisions in new branch, after you make a branch do a merge. Merge into new branch all the revisions from main line that you want there.

I see now that there is a third way. You can make a branch from HEAD revision, but then do a "reverse merge", to remove unwanted revisions. Just select that option when merging.

[image: Reverse merge example]

Comment: thanks for your response, actually i want to remove the files (in new branch) that i have committed in the revisions mentioned in the question.

Comment: Do you want to remove files from whole repository because of some security issue, or do you want a new branch without some files? First case is complicated, but in second case just branch from last revision that does not have those files.

Comment: Or, third case, do you want to revert some revisions from your main branch, but don't really need a new branch?

Comment: Actually my case is : i want files from revision 1503, after this revision till revision 1574 i don't want these files in new branch, and after revision 1574 till revision 1590 i want these files too in my new branch. In simple words, i just want to remove files committed in revisions 1504 till 1574.